# Plotting the correlation between specific columns in a matrix using "corrgram"

Tags: r

Assuming that I have matrix M = (A|B|C) where A,B, and C are columns in M.

Using the `corrgram` function of the `corrgram` package in R, how can I plot the correlation between A, in the one hand, and B and C on the other hand? In other words I'm not interested in plotting all the pairwise correlations between the three columns, but only: `corr(A,B)` and `corr(A,C)`

Comment: Why not just feed corrgram two columns at a time i.e `corrgram(df[,1:2])` for columns A and B and `corrgram(df[,c(1,3])` for columns A and C.

Comment: Thanks CCuritis for the suggestion, but I need both correlation values to appear in the same plot

Answer (score 2):

You could calculate the correlation for the complete matrix and then manually set some correlations to NA.  For example:

```
library(corrgram)
corrgram(iris)
dat <- cor(iris[,1:4])
corrgram(dat)
dat2 <- dat
dat2[1:2,3:4] <- dat2[3:4,1:2] <- NA
corrgram(dat2)
```